# Is there a library for crafting all kinds of Bluetooth packets?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Scapy is a library for crafting any kinds of ip packets in python. Is there something similar for bluetooth? I have looked at libraries such as bleno and noble for nodejs but they allow discovery and advertisements for BLE.

Answer (score 0):

> Scapy is a library for crafting any kinds of ip packets in python. Is
>   there something similar for bluetooth?

Scapy does support bluetooth: it's included in the default layers
https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/bluetooth.py